# Raspberry Pi Visitor Management System with Face Recognition and Data Storage

Tags: automation, raspberry-pi, face-detection

I have been given a project to develop a system that recognizes faces of visitors.
So, the only thing that crossed my mind was Raspberry Pi.

Basically, I want it to

1. Recognize face, store the face and request the visitor to enter their detail such as Name, ID number etc in a spreadsheet.
2. Store the recognized face in a storage.
3. Recognize the face of the visitor next time he visits the premise.
4. Keeps a log of the visitors entered the premise in a separate spreadsheet.

Thank you.

Comment: Hi there! What you're asking isn't very "Basically". Facial recognition is not a simple process. Have you tried googling for facial recognition libraries?

Comment: Hi ikkentim! Yeah, I tried but they were just projects for facial recognition and alerting system. Couldnt find anything specific that met my requirements.